# How to configure officesip server audio codec to be compatible with jssip

Tags: javascript, sip, sip-server, jssip

I am getting the following error message while trying to make call with jssip to officesip server

> Incompatible SDP SIP/2.0 488 Not AcceptableHere

I found out that this is due to the fact that no common codecs between jssip on browser(Mozilla) and officesip server

I was able to log and figure that my jssip was sending this as acceptable codec

> m=audio 59360 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101

But I don't know how to configure officesip server with similar audio codec. Or how to find out what audio codec is officesip working with so that if possible configure jssip to send those as acceptable codec.

**EDIT:**
Here is the INVITE
[image]

Comment: does this *"officesip"* have any documentation you can read?

Comment: https://officesip.com/index.html doesn't say much other than how to install and set up

Comment: Can you post the initial SIP INVITE's SDP body? This will show the list of codecs supported in the INVITE.